# How to isolate bad sectors on a hard disk in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bad-sectors

If I know that a hard disk has bad sectors, how can I "mark" them so that Windows 7 doesn't write to them when I copy files and stuff?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Microsoft, running a regular (or full) format (as opposed to a "quick" format) on a partition will mark all bad sectors within the partition (emphasis mine):

> When you choose to run a regular format on a volume, files are removed from the volume that you are formatting **and the hard disk is scanned for bad sectors**. The scan for bad sectors is responsible for the majority of the time that it takes to format a volume. <sub>[source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302686)</sub>

In Vista and later, this is accomplished [by writing zeros to the entire partition.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941961)

Running a full format on a disk is as simple as right-clicking on the disk, selecting Format, and unchecking the quick format box:

[image: format checkbox]

Note that a full format takes a lot more time than a quick format. The time scales with the size of the disk (i.e. big disks will take more time to format than small ones).

Comment: This is what I ended up doing on a hard drive with bad sectors - the linux equivilent would be mkfs -c. If its got bad sectors, it may be sign of other nasty things happening, so, be careful and don't keep anything critical and not backed up on it

Comment: k i`m going to try this after i finish copying existing stuff on another hdd. I think it has bad sectors bc I didn't use the hdd for a long time, and I kept the hdd out of the original case

Answer (score 9):

This is done automatically by the OS and NTFS.  To check this now, just run CHKDSK.  Any bad sectors are marked and are not used. CHKDSK /R will try to recover the bad sector.

One (of several!) ways to get there: open Windows Explorer; right click on the drive and select Properties from the context menu; select Tools tab; select Check Now.  This runs on the next reboot because it can't make changes to files that are in use.

**Note:** You must be logged in on an **administrator account** to check your disk at this level.  You may also get a UAC prompt.

If you want to run CHKDSK directly:

1. Click on Windows Start button; type `comma` in the search box; select `Command Prompt` from the list to open a Command Prompt window (or right click on it; select Run as administrator from the context menu; etc.)
2. Type `CHKDSK /?` to get a list of options (upper or lowercase doesn't matter).
3. Type `CHKDSK C: /F /R` to check your C: drive for errors and automatically repair them.
4. Restart so scan runs.

I assume you're referring to a standard rotating hdd with NTFS format (though FAT isn't really different for this answer).  Solid state drives handle this problem internally.

A few bad sectors (typically size of 4k but even 64k if optimized for storing large files) on a 50 GB, 500 GB, or 2 TB disk is not worth worrying about (and if the drive is only a few GB, maybe it is time to replace it).

I suppose if you really want to fiddle, you could partition around the bad tracks that contain the bad sectors (so the read/write heads don't pass so directly over them) but if your time is worth a more than $1/day or you're that worried, consider buying a new disk.  I think I've seen some software that semi-automates this but I have a hard time coming up with a scenario where I would want to do this.  (I look forward to seeing good stories in the comments though!)

From Command Prompt

```
chkdsk /?
CHKDSK [volume[[path]filename]]] [/F] [/V] [/R] [/X] [/I] [/C] [/L[:size]] [/B]


  volume          Specifies the drive letter (followed by a colon),
                  mount point, or volume name.
  filename        FAT/FAT32 only: Specifies the files to check for fragmentation.
  /F              Fixes errors on the disk.
  /V              On FAT/FAT32: Displays the full path and name of every file
                  on the disk.
                  On NTFS: Displays cleanup messages if any.
  /R              Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information
                  (implies /F).
  /L:size         NTFS only:  Changes the log file size to the specified number
                  of kilobytes.  If size is not specified, displays current
                  size.
  /X              Forces the volume to dismount first if necessary.
                  All opened handles to the volume would then be invalid
                  (implies /F).
  /I              NTFS only: Performs a less vigorous check of index entries.
  /C              NTFS only: Skips checking of cycles within the folder
                  structure.
  /B              NTFS only: Re-evaluates bad clusters on the volume
                  (implies /R)

The /I or /C switch reduces the amount of time required to run Chkdsk by
skipping certain checks of the volume.
```

Comment: Note that the /R parameter implies (or includes, if you prefer) the /F parameter. Thus, while including /F with /R won't do any harm, it is redundant to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't dropped drive and you have just 1-2 have bad sectors:

1) Scan with **HDtune** then find bad sectors `lba` (ex : 10000000)

2) Download **HDDreg.iso** , write to USB Flash drive (or CD) and boot from it >  select your disk > select option 3 ( regenerate all sectors in range ) >  write `lba` and start operation .

3) Then rescan with HDtune : If didn't fixed , format drive with windows, but don't thick "Quick format" checkbox (When it formats , it will hide sector).

4) If still didn't fixed,try this - install hard disk sentinel > select disk > open surface scan > select "reinitailize disk surface" and start test. It will remap bad sector to spare area . "Reallocated sectors" SMART attiribute will improve