# Bad sectors in the same place?

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, repair, bad-sectors

My disk work perfectly but every time I found lot of bad sectors between the range 4000 Mb  to 6000 Mb and remap them with tools Victoria or Hdd-Regenrator then CHKDSK /f /r.

Can I make that range filled forever by dummy file or something ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/655082/how-to-isolate-bad-sectors-on-a-hard-disk-in-windows-7

Comment: is not the same !

Comment: Does `chkdsk /r` not find all the bad sectors?  It should map whatever it finds to the "bad block list" which prevents it from being allocated to any file.

Comment: yes every time my system fail to start but after do remap and chkdsk /r it back, the problem is these bad sectors appear only in this 2GB (4G-6G from start of disk)

Comment: Instead of making a reserve at the place where there are troubles blocks empty partition, you suffer perversions. Knew a figure, he reanimated again on a floppy disk 20, carried a block of 100 floppy disks and three times they all copied, and then home at copying what downloaded. Very similar).

Comment: If you keep finding new bad sectors, your disk is not working perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sectors of your disk are like this:

01234**5**6789

First time you got number 5. Second time maybe number 4 o 6. And so on!

Your disk is going bad: backup all data and replace it. Never trust a disk with bad sectors!