# Does a "Full Format" on a modern Windows system really check for bad sectors?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, formatting, bad-sectors

First things first: I know I could use CHKDSK or any other third-party tool to detect bad sectors but this question is especially dedicated to whether a "Full Format" on modern Windows systems checks for bad sectors.

I've found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/655090/1109379) which says:

> > When you choose to run a regular format on a volume, files are removed from the volume that you are formatting **and the hard disk is scanned for bad sectors**. The scan for bad sectors is responsible for the majority of the time that it takes to format a volume. <sub>[source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302686)</sub>
>
> In Vista and later, this is accomplished [by writing zeros to the entire partition.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941961)

The link for the first quote to the Microsoft pages is dead, the link for the second is alive but only says this (emphasize mine):

> "The behavior of the format command changed in Windows Vista and later Windows versions. By default in Windows Vista and later versions, **the format command writes zeros to the whole disk when a full format is performed**. In Windows XP and earlier versions of Windows, the format command doesn't write zeros to the whole disk when a full format is performed."

Microsoft only speaks about that in any modern Windows version beginning at Vista doing a "Full Format" would perform a complete zero-write to the hard disk, but they do not say that the zero-writing process would be connected to a check for bad sectors.

What I am basically looking for is an alive link to the first or any similar quote from Microsoft itself, confirming a "Full Format" on any modern Windows (7, 8 and/or 10) system would perform a bad sector check by writing the zeroes OR any proof that it does that (maybe by personal experience).

Thank you for your time. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Format changed starting with Windows Vista>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/format-command-not-write-zeros-to-disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Does a "Full Format" on modern Windows systems check for bad sectors?

By implication, yes.

The documentation for the `format` command says:

> Applies to: Windows 10, Windows Server 2016

...

> `/q`  Performs a quick format. Deletes the file table and the root
> directory of a previously formatted volume, **but does not perform a
> sector-by-sector scan for bad areas**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

This implies that a full format (not using the `/q` option) **does** check for bad sectors.

In addition:

> The format command creates a new root directory and file system for the disk. **It can also check for bad areas on the disk**, and it can delete all data on the disk. To be able to use a new disk, you must first use this command to format the disk.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source [format | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/format)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a Full Format checks for bad sectors.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/format

> The format command creates a new root directory and file system for
> the disk. It can also check for bad areas on the disk, and it can
> delete all data on the disk. To be able to use a new disk, you must
> first use this command to format the disk

.